# WordPress check if post modified date was more than 1 week ago

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

Ok so I have this code and im not sure exactly how to go about checking if the post modified date was more than a week ago.

So if the post was modified more than a week ago it should echo modified.

The code:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
            if (count($sticky) > 0) {
                $stringSticky = implode(",", $sticky);
                $postsModifiedCheck = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "SELECT ID, post_modified
                    FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`
                    WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
                    AND ID IN ($stringSticky)"
                );

                $now = new DateTime();
                $currentDateTime = $now->getTimestamp();

                foreach ($postsModifiedCheck as $post) {
                    if ($currentDateTime > $post->post_modified) {
                        echo "modified";
                    }
                }
            }
```

So at the moment it will echo "modified", just not sure how to modify the dates to echo "modified" if `$post->post_modified` more than a week ago.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is how I solved the problem.
While in the loop use this code:

```
$weekAgo = strtotime('-1 week');

foreach ($postsModifiedCheck as $post) :
    if (intval(strtotime($post->post_modified)) < intval($weekAgo)) unstick_post( $post->ID );
endforeach;
```

The code will check if the post modified date was more than one week ago and unstick the post.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

check your formats -

```
var_dump($currentDateTime .' <- current date - modified date -> '.$post->post_modified );
```

see if they are the same format, 
if they are not the same format, force them to be the same [like this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) 
then when you get to that point - just create a variable where you check the difference f.eks

```
if($currentDateTime - $post->post_modified >= 7){echo 'shiit, It has been modified over a week ago'; }
```

This should help you on your way